# Best way to check if an item is a form element

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there an easier way to write this? Is there a common class that all of these share, but don't share with `div`, `a`, `span`, etc.

```
if(
  el instanceof HTMLInputElement || 
  el instanceof HTMLButtonElement || 
  el instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement
)
```

Maybe something like this:

```
if(el instance HTMLFormItemElement)
```

I need to use this from time to time and I don't want to be constantly writing that everytime. The only thing I can think of doing is placing that in a function, but maybe there is another way?

If you write this as a function, then you get a possible error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either write a function (as you mentioned) or you can check if the "form" property from the element is presented/not null.
Example: an HTMLInputElement has an "form" property, as described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

"form (Read only: HTMLFormElement object):  Returns a reference to the parent form element."

Comment: So... `el.form instanceof HTMLFormElement`

Comment: What if the element isn't in a form?

Comment: `el.form` will return `null` if the element isn't in a form.  (`el.form` returns `undefined` for non-form elements.)  So `el.form === null || el.form instanceof HTMLFormElement` should do the trick.

Comment: We can make it even shorter: `el.form !== undefined`